# Uncaught ReferenceError: errorCheck is not defined

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I am trying to display an alert whenever the value inside of an input area is empty. I have done this in JavaScript and I keep getting the error:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: errorCheck is not defined"
```

It also says that my `onclick` is `undefined`. What is supposed to happen is when the user clicks the submit button is it supposed to look at the `lastName` input area and check if it is empty and if it is it will display an `alert` to the user.

HTML:

```
<input TYPE="button" VALUE="Submit" onClick="errorCheck()" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function errorCheck() {
  if ((document.getElementsByID('lastName').value == "") {
    alert("the last name area is empty")
  }
}
```

Comment: where exactly is `errorCheck` defined, if its not in the global scope it wont be visible to the onClick attribute

Comment: You have a typo - an extra `(` in your `if` statement.

Comment: There is nothing like `document.getElementsByID()`. It should be `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Does that mean I need to put errorCheck into the body?

Comment: Well if the typo that lwalden points out is in your actually code it will cause your function to not be defined as you will have a syntax error. So fix the typo and see if that fixes it, if it doesnt than you have to make sure its in global scope ie not defined in an object or in another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. You have an extra `(` in the `if` statement.
2. `getElementsByID` should be `getElementById`

This code works for me

```
function errorCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('lastName').value == "") {
        alert("the last name area is empty")
    }
}
```

The above code can be put in `<script>` tag inside `<head>` or `<body>` tag. If you want to put the code in an external .js file, you need to add a reference to the .js file.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r7w1umnt/